# ListView styling in JavaFX

Tags: listview, javafx, javafx-8, fxml, styling

I have a listview. I want to change the color of the background and the text fill. I have tried doing the following:

```
playlistView.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue; -fx-text-fill: black;");
```

But, this doesn't work. However, the following is working:

```
playlistView.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 24px; -fx-font-family: 'SketchFlow Print';");
```

Can you please tell me how to get the background and text-fill to work? Thank you.

Comment: The background color comes from the individual [list cells](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#listcell): style those instead.

Comment: Can you please explain the styling statement? Thank you.

Comment: Style the cells. You are styling the list itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the following CSS styles:

```
.list-view .list-cell:even {
-fx-background-color: blue;
-fx-text-fill: black;
}
.list-view .list-cell:odd {
-fx-background-color: blue;
-fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

1. Save the content of this style in a `lisStyles.css`.
2. Add the URL for the `lisStyles.css` style sheet to the scene:

   `scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("lisStyles.css").toExternalForm());`

Answer (score 9):

You are styling the `ListView`, but the background color is determined by styles on the list cells. So style the cells. If you change the value of the looked-up color `-fx-control-inner-background` you will preserve both the "striping" of alternate rows, and the changing text color so that it contrasts the background. Use

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-control-inner-background: blue ;
}
```

in an external style sheet. Note the striping is very subtle (almost invisible) when the background is this dark: you might want to adjust it with

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-control-inner-background: blue ;
    -fx-control-inner-background-alt: derive(-fx-control-inner-background, 50%);
}
```

As a quick hack, you can set that looked-up color directly on the list view, and it will propagate to the cells it contains:

```
playlistView.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background: blue;");
```

however, it is better (better separation of code, and more robust) to define it on the cells in an external style sheet.